# Unable to resolve Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem where certain numbers are taken and appended into the list.
After that I want to see that the first element is smaller than the next element if yes then remove it from the list.
But during comparison it is throwing this error.
I am new to python and don't know how to resolve this

I've tried to take the input in a different way but still can't solve it.

```
n=int(input())
l = []
m=input().split()
l.append(m)
print(m)
for i in m:
    j=i+1
    if i<j:
        m.remove(i)
    print(m)
```

It is showing the given error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    j=i+1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: You are trying to do some calculation with string, this value `m` is a string value like `['blabla']`. Inside the loop you'll get `'blabla'` and you are trying to add this string value to some integer.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your input, I can tell you that the elements of `m` are strings. The return type of `input()` is a string and you've created a list of strings in `m`. You can do `j = int(i) + 1` to make that line of code work, but you'll have a lot more work to do to solve your overall problem. `i<j` will always evaluate to `True` given the above line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i got my mistake. will be careful from next time

Answer (score 0):

`m = input().split()` returns an iterable of strings, split by whitespace. If these are supposed to be integers, you've got to cast it to an integer. Do:

```py
n=int(input())
l = []
m=input().split()
l.append(m)
print(m)
for i in m:
    j=int(i)+1  # i is cast to an integer
    if i<j:
        m.remove(i)
    print(m)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i got my mistake. will be careful from next time